# How do you specify multiple value for querying on multiple column index on pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following code.

```
d = {'a': [1, 1, 1,2], 'b': [2, 2, 6,6], 'c': ['AA','BB','CC','DD']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
df.set_index(['a','b'],inplace=True)
print(df)
print(df.loc[1,2])
```

This is my indexed data frame:

```
a b    
1 2  AA
  2  BB
  6  CC
2 6  DD
```

And this is the output when I select a = 1 and b = 2 on the indexed columns.

```
a b    
1 2  AA
  2  BB
```

I would like to be able to select where a = 1 and b in (2,6) based on the index that I set. So, the output result should be:

```
a b    
1 2  AA
  2  BB
  6  CC
```

I tried to use df.loc[1,[2,6]], but that doesn't work. I couldn't find any examples how to do this. Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the index as a tuple:

```
 print(df.loc[[(1,2),(1,6)]])

 #
       c
 a b    
 1 2  AA
   2  BB
   6  CC
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. It seems like an overkill though if you have many combinations. It made me think that it could be easier (not sure if efficient though) to use conditional lookup of  column values instead.